# Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::chekInput()

Tags: php, mysql

```
login.php

<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['login'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(!empty($email) or !empty($password)){
    $email = $getFromU->chekInput($email);<------ошибка
    $password = $getFromU->chekInput($password);

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $error = "Invalid format";
    }else{
        if($getFromU->login($email, $password) === false){
            $error = "The email or password is incorrect";
        }
    }
}else{
    $error = "Please enter username password";
}
}
?>

user.php

<?php
class User {
protected $pdo;

function __construct($pdo){
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
}

public function checkInput($var){
    $var = htmlspecialchars($var);//Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности
    $var = trim($var);//Удаляет пробелы (или другие символы) из начала и конца строки
    $var = stripcslashes($var);//Удаляет экранирование символов, произведенное функцией addcslashes()
    return $var;
}

public function login($email,$password){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email' = :email AND 'password' = :password");//Подготавливает запрос к выполнению и возвращает ассоциированный с этим запросом объект
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);//bindParam — Привязывает параметр запроса к переменной. PDO::PARAM_STR - Представляет типы данных SQL CHAR, VARCHAR и другие строковые типы.
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();//execute — Запускает подготовленный запрос на выполнение

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);//fetch — Извлечение следующей строки из результирующего набора. PDO::FETCH_OBJ: создает анонимный объект со свойствами, соответствующими именам столбцов результирующего набора
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();//rowCount — Возвращает количество строк, модифицированных последним SQL запросом

    if($count > 0){
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
        header('Location: home.php');
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

}
?>

init.php

<?php

include 'database/connection.php';
include 'classes/user.php';
include 'classes/tweet.php';
include 'classes/follow.php';

global $pdo;

session_start();

$getFromU = new User($pdo);
$getFromT = new Tweet($pdo);
$getFromF= new Follow($pdo);

define("BASE_URL", "http://twitter/")
?>
```

Comment: а где вы вызваете функцию chekInput(), я что то не заметил, + самое главное, вызов происходит как static function User::chekInput(), а у вас в примере это не static

Comment: Там где написано ошибка...!!!

Comment: что это такое??

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод называется checkInput, а вы пытаетесь вызвать chekInput.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток...
Вот на скооую руку написал...

```
 <?php
// login.php file...

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
if(isset($_POST['pass'])){              

if($_POST['email'] == '' || $_POST['pass'] == ''){
/* Не введен Email или Пароль... */
} else {
$login = htmlspecialchars(trim(stripcslashes($_POST['email'])));
$password = htmlspecialchars(trim(stripcslashes($_POST['pass'])));

userLogin($login, $password);

}
} else { /* Не пришел Пароль...*/ }                
} else { /* Не пришел Email... */ }

function userLogin($l, $p){
// $l - Логин (email)
// $p - Пароль

// Здесь делаете проверку в MySql и так далее...

}

?>// End
```

Comment: такая ошибка Warning: Missing argument 1 for User::__construct(), called in C:\php\OpenServer\domains\twitter\includes\login.php on line 7 and defined in C:\php\OpenServer\domains\twitter\core\classes\user.php on line 5

Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::chekInput() in C:\php\OpenServer\domains\twitter\includes\login.php on line 8

Comment: а pdo нужно для проверки совпадения данных

Comment: Изменил пример..

Comment: Проверку можно устроить и без pdo...

Comment: ничего не поменялось, такая же ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте в методе `checkInput` убрать `addcslashes() return $var;` ...

Comment: И что это вообще такое? `addcslashes() return $var;`

Comment: addcslashes()-это к комментарию относиться

Comment: Понял.. удалите вместе с return $var;

Comment: та тоже самое, к сожалению ничего не поменялось

Comment: Насколько я понял ошибка появляется в файле проверки полей заполненых данными юзера?

Comment: Укажите какие есть поля ?

Comment: Только login и pass?

Comment: email и password

Comment: Изменил ответ.. попробуйте мой метод проверки даных пользователя..

Comment: Скажете роботает или нет.. ибо у меня все ок

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо)